# How do I declare an extern variable in assembly code?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, visual-c++, extern

**Asm.asm**

```
.code 
OurFunc proc
   sub edi, 0
   jmp[jmpBk]
Ourfunc endp
end
```

**Main.cpp**

```
extern DWORD jmpBk;
extern "C" void OurFunc();

int main()
{
     ourFunc();         
}
```

I get the following error

```
1>Assembling Asm.asm...
1>Asm.asm(4): error A2006: undefined symbol : jmpBk
```

This isn't the actual code but how would I use the external DWORD variable in the .asm file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are using MASM. If so, here's the code:

```
externdef jmpBk : near
```